# Spring Batch - customize batch related tables

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to add more columns to `Spring batch's` `BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` table and I am trying to implement custom save operation for that table?

After googling I couldn't able to find any relevant document.

Even any reference document would be helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spring batch out of box does not provide any such functionality .**

Ideally you should not make any changes to spring batch's BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE table or to any table of the spring batch table for that matter .

Following are the reasons .

- All the functionality that spring batch provides is very much
  dependent to those six tables , for example restart , stop etc are
  all dependent on all these tables , so better not to make any changes
  to these tables .
- Spring batch have already implemented DAOs for all these six tables ,
  if you try to add more columns to any of these tables then these DAOs
  might not work at all or if you want to make it work , you will have 
  to make a hell lot of changes .

Finally if you want to add extra column then better to create new table in the same Database and write your won DAOs and be careful with the database transaction management .